# why Enum.ToString not acceptable as const string for Attribute parameter string type?

Tags: c#, string, enums, constants

[TL;DR]
why `const string SomeConstString = SomeEnum.OneEnumValue.ToString();` is not allowed in C# even if it can be processed in compile-time?

Below attribute definition is from [Azure WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/663a508e8a851629c26a51e7de3af36629dfd120/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/ServiceBusTriggerAttribute.cs);

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
[DebuggerDisplay("{DebuggerDisplay,nq}")]
public sealed class ServiceBusTriggerAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _queueName;
    private readonly string _topicName;
    private readonly string _subscriptionName;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ServiceBusTriggerAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="queueName">The name of the queue to which to bind.</param>
    public ServiceBusTriggerAttribute(string queueName)
    {
        ...
    }
```

And the usage of the code is as below;

```
public static void GetBapulActivityFromTopic(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("SomeConstString")] BrokeredMessage message,
        TextWriter log)
    {
        ...
    }
```

In above usage, I understand that `"SomeConstString"` should be `const string` type as the value has to be compile-time constant.

But why `SomeEnum.OneEnumValue.ToString()` cannot be a compile-time constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# (and the CLR/.NET) does not have the notion of `constexpr` that C++ does, unfortunately. Because the CLR does not support it means that the compiler cannot make that assumption, hence it fails.

But FWIW, the CLR does *not* process your expression at compile-time, it will always be evaluated at runtime.

The workaround, in modern C#, is to use constructs like `nameof` and T4.

More specifically, `SomeEnum.OneEnumValue` itself is a field-accessor, and the `.ToString()` is a `virtual` instance method. Hypothetically another CLR environment *could* legally add some trickery that makes the `ToString()` method not predictable at all (e.g. taking localization/thread culture into consideration), so then it demonstrably would not be able to be processed at compile-time at all.

Another counter-argument: what if `SomeEnum` were to be defined in a separable assembly (`.dll`) file completely? The linking between assemblies only happens at runtime, so if you were to replace the assembly that contained `SomeEnum` then the runtime cannot assume `.ToString()` would return the same value.

Also, note that `static readonly` and `const` are not equivalent:

If you have AssemblyA that references AssemblyB, and AssemblyA uses a `const String` defined in AssemblyB, then AssemblyA will actually contain a *copy* of the const value from AssemblyB, even if AssemblyB is replaced at runtime. That's part of the nature of `const` in the CLR.

Answer (score 5):

Even though `SomeEnum.OneEnumValue` is a `const`, invoking a method on it is not a compile-time constant expression according to C# Language Specification. Here is a partial list of what is allowed:

> - Literals (including the `null` literal).
> - References to `const` members of class and struct types.
> - References to members of enumeration types.
> - References to `const` parameters or local variables
> - Parenthesized sub-expressions, which are themselves constant expressions.

Method invocations are not allowed in constant expressions. See section N.19 for a complete list.

If you are using C# 6, you can use [`nameof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead, which produces a compile-time constant:

```
const string SomeConstString = nameof(SomeEnum.OneEnumValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `Enum.ToString()` is just a regular method call. It contains it's own logic inside. For example, if will check if given enum has `[Flags]` attribute and if yes - will convert enum value to string in a different way. C# compiler won't call arbitrary methods at compile time, so it cannot be compile-time constant.

And anyway it't not a very good idea to use enums in this case. For example, azure queue name can start with a number and contain dashes (as I remember), while enum cannot. Maybe today you don't use such queue names but who knows what will happen tomorrow. So it's better just define static class with public constants.